# How do I plot a Lyapunov Exponent Graph with 2D array on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have the following code to generate a 2d array but I can't seem to get the graph out. This is the graph I wish to get.

[image]

```
close all 
clear all

rvalues = 20:1:200;
N=100; 
fs=5;
r=rvalues; 
x=rand(1);
a=1;
X=zeros(N,length(r));
for n=1:.3*N 
    x=(1/a).*mod(r.*x.*(1-sin(x)),a); 
    X(n,:)=x;
end
lyapExp = lyapunovExponent(X,fs)
figure (2), hold on
for n=.3*N:N 
    x=(1/a).*mod(r.*x.*(1-sin(x)),a); 
    X(n,:)=x;
    lyapExp = lyapunovExponent(X,fs)
  
end
hold off
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly want you want but, to avoid suppressing the plot you can call the function `lyapunovExponent(X,fs);` without a return/output variable. This will result in MATLAB opening a new figure and plotting the following:

[image: Output Plot]

```
clear
close all 

rvalues = 20:1:200;
N = 100; 
fs = 5;
r = rvalues; 
x = rand(1);
a = 1;
X = zeros(N,length(r));


for n=1: 0.3*N 
    x=(1/a).*mod(r.*x.*(1-sin(x)),a); 
    X(n,:) = x;
end

lyapExp = lyapunovExponent(X,fs);
%Calling without a return variable so plot is not suppressed%
lyapunovExponent(X,fs);
```

Comment: I need to plot it against r as the x axis thought.

Do I just add in plot (r,lyapExp)

Comment: I'm confused why are you using a for-loop if no values other than `n` change within the loop? Before dealing with the `lyapunovExponent()` function try to ensure that the signal `x` comes out as expected. To calculate the Lyapunov Exponents against `r` it makes sense to access and use one value from vector `r` on each loop iteration.

Comment: I am generating a 2d array of values. So for r = 20, it will generate like 100 different values of X. then for r = 21 it will generate another 100 different values of X. At the end of the day I would get an array of 100 X1801 data value and wish to plot the Lyapunov exponent of that array against r. Hope that clarifies. Is it not possible to calculate the Lyapunov exponent using a 2d array of data?

Comment: Do you mean for `x` to change into a vector on the second iteration onwards? Unknowingly I think the approach currently is mixing up vectorization and a looping method. Have you had a chance to verify all your values in the workspace window?

Comment: Yup they seem alright when I use the 2 for loops to generate the bifurcation graph. Not sure why it didn't work for the Lyapunov Exponent.